# Vim: Custom tab complete that retrieves results from a bash script

Tags: vim, tab-completion

I have written a bash script finds rhymes for any word. I would like to be able to tab complete the results of this script.

I imagine this is possible with vimscript. The basic steps are look at the line above the current line, pass that line as an argument, and then show the tab completion view (possibly via some plugin) and show the result returned from the script.

I've written some vim script before, but I don't quite know where to start with executing a bash script or opening the tab completion menu. Does anyone know how this might be possible?

Comment: If you explain the logic of how the rhymes are found, it will be easy to analyse. I think you are finding them at end of each line. Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, the bash script (which is really just a ruby script) can take any string, and then returns a list of words that rhyme. So ideally, this vimscript would take the line above the cursor, and send it to the bash script, and then show the tab completion list with the result.

Comment: If anyone else, comes in and answers the tab completion portion of this question, I'll happily grant another bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) and [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) for this. Here's a sample key mapping.

```
inoremap <expr> <c-x><c-k> fzf#complete('./script.sh ' . getline(line(".")-1))
```

`fzf#complete` can run the script and open a menu with the output of that script. You can fuzzy search the output or use arrow keys to select an entry. Selected entry gets inserted in the vim buffer.

`getline(line(".")-1)` passes the line above current line to the script called `script.sh`.

This is not exactly tab completion like you asked, but it's serving the same purpose and also has fuzzy search through results from your script.

Comment: Sorry it has taken me a few days to get to this answer - I've been under a deadline laterly. Friggin cool, though. I'm going to upvote it for the moment, and give it a couple more days to see if anyone can answer the tab completion portion, just because I think this needs a canonical answer. You'll get the accepted answer/bounty if a tab completion answer doesn't come through.